# Does M3 AST support Java 8 features?

Tags: rascal

When retrieving the ASTs from projects in Java 8 or above, lambda expressions lead to a null value in the AST. It also seems that there is no AST node for lambda expressions. Does this mean that the M3 model does not yet support this?

Comment: Hi Steffan; that's right! we have an open issue for it here: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/1540 If you have a strong need for it, we might be able to push the priority up.

Comment: Hi Jurgen, thanks for your answer! It's just for a study project, I'll probably manage to figure something out.

Comment: ok cool. let us know if you get stuck